# Oracle update query using partition

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have following sample data in Oracle v.12 database

```
ID | NAME   | DML_TYPE  | FND_FILESEQNO | FND_FILERBA

---------------------------------------------------------

1  | name1a | insert    | 1             | 1

1  | name1b | update    | 1             | 2

2  | name2a | insert    | 2             | 1

2  | name2b | update    | 2             | 2

....

....

....
```

I want following 2 transactions to happen

1. `delete old records (FND_FILESEQNO + FND_FILERBA) partition by 'ID' column`
2. `update latest record DML_TYPE = 'insert'`

So eventually, if I query this table, I should get following result...

```
ID | NAME   | DML_TYPE  | FND_FILESEQNO | FND_FILERBA

---------------------------------------------------------

1  | name1b | insert    | 1             | 2

2  | name2b | insert    | 2             | 2
```

Many thanks

Comment: So do you want one procedure that does both operations or you are okay to have two separate queries: First that performs deletion and second that perform update?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
MERGE INTO STACTOVER a
USING (  SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT   STACTOVER.*,Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)rn 
FROM  STACTOVER)WHERE rn>1
  )b 
ON
(a.ID = b.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET a.dml_type = 'insert'
  DELETE WHERE a.NAME != b.NAME ;
```